# Okular review (annotations toolbar) not available

Tags: kde, pdf, okular

I have been using Okular (1.3.3) on Ubuntu (18.04) for a while now and feel pretty confident in my ability to be productive in it. However, suddenly, I am lost.

I opened a PDF (as I have done 100s of times) and pressed <kbd>F6</kbd> to get the annotations toolbar. Nothing happened. I checked for stuck keys on my keyboard. Nothing changed. I closed the PDF and opened another PDF and everything works as expected. I went back and opened the troublesome PDF.

Under the Tools menu, Review (<kbd>F6</kbd>) is grayed out (disabled). I checked the file to see if it was read-only. It was not.

Any ideas why the annotation toolbar would not be available in some PDF but would in others? Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

Try turning off the **Obey DRM**, in **Settings** -> **Configure Okular**

Comment: Hi and welcome. If you could [edit] and expand upon your answer, if possible, explaining why your solution would help, then that would be great. As it stands, your answer is a little brief.

Comment: I had the same issue, and this fix resolved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly this PDF (your troublesome.pdf) is just readable not editable. You can change it by this command:

```
$ qpdf -decrypt just_readable.pdf editable.pdf
```

Then <kbd>F6</kbd> will work.

Answer (score 0):

Since the other pdf file works fine — It seems Okular does not recognize the troubled file as a legitimate pdf. You might want (if not already done) to create a new pdf file & see what happens.

Comment: This seems like more of a comment than an answer 